# asp.net membership forms cookie not showing logged in across subdomains

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication, session-cookies

we're using ASP.NET Membership for authentication at the root domain (www.domain.com) and the redirecting the user to a subdomain (sub.domain.com).  When the user logins in from www they are being redirected to the login page on the subdomain when they should be showing as logged in instead.

Both the machine key and the forms element in the web.config are identical.

In the event log we get

> Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied was invalid.

turns out it was a MS Security update that did it.

UPDATE
[security update available](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/28/asp-net-security-update-now-available.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

What's worked for me is to set the `domain` attribute of the `forms` element to be `.domain.com`. This should allow the user to log in on at www.domain.com and then be logged in when accessing sub.domain.com. I've tested this having hacked my hosts file and it works okay.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" domain=".domain.com" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: that's the weird thing, this works fine in our UAT environment but not production.

Comment: @Steven If the cookie is actually being submitted to subdomain.domain.com (something you can check using Fiddler) and the configuration for the machineKey etc. is the same on both servers, then I would investigate whether a proxy or firewall in the path to the server is mangling the cookie. You could run a test page on the subdomain.domain.com server that reads the raw value of the authentication cookie to make sure that it's not getting filtered out between the client and IIS and that the value is the same as that set by the www.domain.com server.